# Create rails 4 app on rails 5 machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails 5 installed on my machine, but now I want to create a rails 4 app.
I use this code: rails *4.2.6* app_name
But these errors come out:

> /home/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (= 4.2.6) - did find: [railties-5.0.0.1] (Gem::LoadError)
>   Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0:/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global', execute`gem env`for more information
>       from /home/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in`to_spec'
>       from /home/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
>       from /home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rails:22:in`'
>       from /home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
>       from /home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'

Hope someone could help me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using RVM. So if I were you I would create a new gemset and install whatever version of Rails you want to work with.

For example

```
$ rvm gemset create new_gemset
$ rvm gemset use new_gemset
$ gem install rails -v 4.2.6
```

Now you should be able to create a new rails app with your `rails new app_name` command.